# CSS side by side div's auto equal widths

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width:90%;height:100px;background-color:Gray;">
    <div id="one" style="height:100px;background-color:Green;float:left;"></div>
    <div id="two" style="height:100px;background-color:blue;float:left;"></div>
    <div id="three" style="height:100px;background-color:Red;float:left;"></div>
</div>
```

I have a parent div which will contain 2 or 3 child divs. I want child divs to take equal widths automatically.

Thank You

Comment: so you dont want to specifiy a `width` for the child-divs? impossible with just CSS. Your closest solution would be to give them `width:33.33%`. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/wBv5r/

Answer (score 104, accepted):

It's not impossible. It's not even particularly hard, with the use of `display: table`.

This solution [will work](http://caniuse.com/css-table) in modern browsers. It won't work in IE7.

http://jsfiddle.net/g4dGz/ *(three `div`s)*
http://jsfiddle.net/g4dGz/1/ *(two `div`s)*

**CSS:**

```css
#wrapper {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;

    width:90%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:Gray;
}
#wrapper div {
    display: table-cell;
    height:100px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="one">one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one</div>
    <div id="two">two two two two two two</div>
    <div id="three">three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would you coerce this to work in IE7. I'm interested to know. Excellent solution Thirty!

Comment: @Chris: I can't think of a pure CSS fix for IE7, but there's a JavaScript fix: http://tanalin.com/en/projects/display-table-htc/

Comment: How is this method viewed in best practice? Is it alright to use `display: table` when the content isn't tabular data?

Comment: @Rikki: Yeah, it's fine. The stigma with tables is when `<table>`s are used in HTML to hold non-tabular data, which is bad from a semantic point of view. Using `display: table-cell` is no different to using `float: left` to position something.

Answer (score 44):

in modern browsers, you can use [flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

[three divs](http://jsfiddle.net/kxL16wzy/) example

[two divs](http://jsfiddle.net/mh93n5g4/) example

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    display: flex;    
    width:90%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:Gray;
}
#wrapper div {
    flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="one">one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one</div>
    <div id="two">two two two two two two</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was especially useful when using `display:table` and the like was no option due to different heights of individual child divs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `width:33%`?

Comment: The question is about a variable number of children. Not exactly 3.

Comment: @jakob.j true but you can add classes to the wrapper like contains_1 contains_2, contains_3 if you have some backend info coming in and you know there is an upper bound on the number of divs. 
Example: .wrapper.contains_4 > div { width: 25% }

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of older browser compatibility, here's a solution that works.

html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.parent{
    height: 200px;
    background: #f00;
}
.parent > div{
    width: calc(100%/3);
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background: #fff;
}
```

**However, to make it dynamic, since you'd know if it'd be 2 or 3 columns, you can put the count in a variable and do internal / inline css:**

//$count = 2 or 3

Internal CSS (recommended)

```
...
<style>
    .parent > div{
        width: calc(100%/<?=$count;?>);
    }
</style>
<body>
...
```

Inline CSS:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div style="calc(100%/<?=$count;?>)"></div>
    <div style="calc(100%/<?=$count;?>)"></div>
    <div style="calc(100%/<?=$count;?>)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't actually answer the question, because it's not actually about a fixed number of cells, but +1 anyway for the use of a function in `width`. You should for instance be able to set `data-columns="4"` in the containing `div`, and then use `width=calc(100%/attr(data-columns));` in the CSS

Answer (score -1):

```
.wrapper > div {
  width: 33.3%;
}
```

This doesn't work in IE <= 6, so you would better add some common class to child divs and create a CSS-rule for it.

Comment: The question is about a variable number of children. Not exactly 3.