# How to fit these divs inside a div to occupy whole horizontal width

Tags: html, css

How can I fit these 3 child boxes (`2 .child, 1 .screen`) inside parent (`.parentDiv`) to perfectly occupy the horizontal space.

I do not want to do this using javascript.
Fiddle for reference, what I want is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/s3zUd/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="screen"></div>
</div>​
```

The .screen element can be before after or a middle element.

**CSS:**

```
#parentDiv {width:600px; height:400px; margin:10px auto; border:1px solid #000}

.child {width:100px; border:1px solid blue; float:left; height:100%}
.screen {float:left; border:1px solid red; height:100%;}

.child, .screen {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; /* Safari */
}
​
```

Comment: You should save your attempt in jsfiddle :)

Comment: If you have the width of two child classes, then the width of screen class can be obtained. What is the **unknown** width?

Comment: @Fari - that way I have to use javascript. If there is no solution using css, I will have to use javascript.

Comment: As I understood, the width of parent div is unknown, so the width of screen class depends on it. Am I true?

Comment: width of parent, child1 and child2 is known while width of screen is not known and to be set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On `.screen`, add `overflow: hidden` and remove `float: left`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/s3zUd/1/

[More information.](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats)

Comment: your solution works for above scenario. But sometimes `.screen` can be between two .child divs. In this case also I need solution.

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question. You can do it visually like this: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/s3zUd/2/. Unfortunately, the order in the HTML has to be like that with this technique. If that's no good, I suggest that you use `display: table-cell` instead, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351634/css-side-by-side-divs-auto-equal-widths/5353082#5353082

Comment: @MotaBOS Also you will have issues with margins and paddings. So I suggest to use `<table>` tag. Goodluck :)

Comment: @thirtydot - added that scenario in question.

Answer (score 0):

The fiddle page isn't loading for me.  Are you trying to split the width of the parent evenly among them?  If so, have you tried setting their width to 33.33%?

```
.child
{
    width: 33.33%;
}

.screen
{
    width: 33.33%;
}
```

Or, for that matter, any set of values where 2*child.width + screen.width = 100%.

Comment: no, the width of the `.screen` div should be set to the remaining space. i.e. `if child1 = 25% and child2 = 35%` then `.screen` should be `40%`

Comment: So can you do it that way, then?  Or are you trying to use a pixel width for one of the elements?

Comment: yes, the width can be in pixels or in percentages. Also I have to take care of margin and padding around these elements which I have not mentioned in question to avoid complication.

Answer (score 0):

Your link is not working. Maybe, the solution you are looking for is floats. Floats help you position elements without using tables or CSS positioning. More about floats [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="screen"></div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.container{width:100%; height:100%;}
.child1{float:left; width:25%; height:100%;}
.child2{width:30%; height:100%;}
.screen{width:45%; height:100%;}
```

Function

```
  function resize()(
{
var mydiv = document.getElementById("child1");
var curr_width = parseInt(mydiv.style.width);

var mydiv2 = document.getElementById("child1");
var curr_width2 = parseInt((mydiv.style.width);

document.getElementById("screen").style.width=(avaliablewidth-curr_width-curr_width2)+"px";
}
```

**CSS3 Solution** Set the container width to available width and add this to your each child element

```
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box; /* Safari */
width:30%//Whatevet width you want it to have
float:left;
```

Comment: There are 3 divs (child1, child2 and screen). screen width must be `available_width - (child1_width + child2_width)`.

Comment: That's fine, can I not do it without javascript. What about using -`moz-box-sizing` ?

Comment: But for that you need to know the size of child1 and child2 beforehand. Is it known beforehand?

Comment: width of child1 and child2 is knows, width of screen is not known.

Comment: And what is avaliable_width? where does it come from?

Comment: width of parent div is also known before hand. It can be width of the document/window/body