# Responsive Layout with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build a responsive layout using bootstrap. I am confused how to code the area below to make sure it works naturally with bootstrap.

According to Twitter Convention i am already using div.row and div.span12. Inside this area i have a box with the border as show below.

There is a box with a border and inside the box i need to have three span of equal width. how do i achieve this using bootstrap.

[image]

http://play.mink7.com/h/minkstock/

Comment: Where is the question? Could you please explain what you want to achieve? "Works naturally" ain't very clear. Would applying the `span3` class to each one of the three elements work for you?

Comment: @MaximeR. i am using a row > span12 and inside that another div#stats-chart to achieve the box. Now i have to add three divs thats of equal width. If i add another Row and Span it gives me a full width outside the box

Comment: u mean to say row>span12>row>span4+span4+span4 ?

Comment: 3*span4 doesn't work for him because he has some additional margins between the red box & the span12

Comment: A solution with `display: table`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5351634/343834 if you want 3 divs of equal width no matter what. Bootstrap's spans will end up one above the other when the window width is reduced.

Comment: Sounds to me like you should look at .row-fluid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equal width divs can be obtained with `display: table`: [CSS side by side div's auto equal widths](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5351634/343834)
Then you'll have 3 divs of equal width no matter what.

Bootstrap's spans will end up one above the other when the window width is reduced but that may be better than three tiny divs of equal width on a smartphone.

Also, you could make use of bootstrap's [responsive utility classes](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) to design different chart headers as needed.