# Auto align multiple divs in another without using a table

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to "auto align" the divs in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hk754/) with a parent with `width:100%`?

It now looks like this:

```
[#-#-#-#-#-#--------------------]
```

But it should look like this:

```
[#-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#]
```

Can this be done using CSS?

Comment: do you have fixed number of child divs or is it dynamically generated??

Comment: childs are fixed width in the fiddle.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351634/css-side-by-side-divs-auto-equal-widths

Comment: It's impossible to distribute elements dynamically with CSS keeping his fixed width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, but unfortunately the support is almost none.
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/

You can use this polyfill to make it work, but I wouldn't count on it.
https://github.com/codler/Grid-Layout-Polyfill

The best solution is using table and table-cell:

```
<div class="table>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hk754/

Answer (score 0):

Change your css to this,

```
.row {
    /*width: 100%;*/
    height: 100px;
    background-color: gray;
    border: 1px solid black;   
}

.common {
    height: 100%; 
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.one {width: 20%; background-color: #FEC3BF;}
.two {width: 10%; background-color: #FE7777;}
.three {width: 25%; background-color: #FE7777;}
.four {width: 20%; background-color: #FEE826;}
.five {width: 10%; background-color: #FEBD5B;}
.six {width: 15%; background-color: #E6FED0;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hk754/8/