# Arrange divs as a grid

Tags: html, css

I got the current code to display a grid of recipes

```
<div class="mt-40">
    <div class="recipe-cont cont mt-15 rounded left mr-15 mb-15">
        <img src="data/2014121601/thumb.png" alt="thumbnail" class="rounded mt-5 ml-5">
    </div>
    <div class="recipe-cont cont mt-15 rounded left mr-15 mb-15">
        <img src="data/2014121602/thumb.png" alt="thumbnail" class="rounded mt-5 ml-5">
    </div>
    <div class="recipe-cont cont mt-15 rounded left mr-15 mb-15">
        <img src="data/2014121603/thumb.png" alt="thumbnail" class="rounded mt-5 ml-5">
    </div>
    <div class="recipe-cont cont mt-15 rounded left mr-15 mb-15 ">
        <img src="data/2014121601/thumb.png" alt="thumbnail" class="rounded mt-5 ml-5">
    </div>
    <div class="recipe-cont cont mt-15 rounded left mr-15 mb-15 ">
        <img src="data/2014121602/thumb.png" alt="thumbnail" class="rounded mt-5 ml-5">
    </div>
    <div class="recipe-cont cont mt-15 rounded left mr-15 mb-15">
        <img src="data/2014121603/thumb.png" alt="thumbnail" class="rounded mt-5 ml-5">
    </div>
    <div class="recipe-cont cont mt-15 rounded left mr-15 mb-15">
        <img src="data/2014121601/thumb.png" alt="thumbnail" class="rounded mt-5 ml-5">
    </div>
</div>
```

.

```
.recipe-cont {
    width: 180px;
    height: 210px;
}
```

The output looks like this:
[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is this:
[image]

The reason it's not working as I want is because I've set **margin-right: 15px**.
I want to easily add new recipes to the list by inserting a new div, so removing the margin on the 5th div will solve the problem temporarily, but it will get problematic when I insert more recipes as it's pushed down one to a new line.

```
mr-15 = margin-right: 15px  
mb-15 = margin-bottom: 15px
```

Help really appreciated!

Comment: That only reason the 5th thumbnail is coming down a line is because there's not enough space for it up there. Calculate how wide your main wrapper that those divs are in, then divide it by 5, then in each portion allocate 15px left-right margin. That should work. However, if you want this to be responsive, go with the percentage. Like each div 18% wide with 1% margin on left-right. You get the idea.

Comment: A good read: http://osvaldas.info/flexbox-based-responsive-equal-height-blocks-with-javascript-fallback

Comment: Thanks for the link, but that is far too advanced for what I'm trying achieve. My site is not responsive.

Comment: Then the precise calculation is what you need. Just calculate what needs to happen. If the image stretches out of the div, give it a beating with `max-width: 100%`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5353082/2745485

Comment: Can you add your css ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:nth-child()` CSS3 selector to specify a style for every 5th element. Like this:

```
.mt-40:nth-child(5n+0) {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

here's a doc: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Be sure to put this declaration AFTER your `.mr-15 { margin-right: 15px }` so that it will cascade.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how you build your css, but you should consider this two links as solution ideas :

- [Box Sizing](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)
- [Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

**Code**

```
* {
    margin:0;   
    padding:0;
    font-size: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    display:inline;
}
```

[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g74tu7qf/3/)

Answer (score -1):

Do not be afraid to use tables, although tables are often frowned upon for website layout and design. When you have tabular data such as this in the content section you can always insert a table in the HTML code.

This way, when you go to insert a new recipe you can just insert a new `<td>` or table data tag. I hope this helps with what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Actually, i think it's a great idea. If you have a fixed number of `td` in a row, you can show a grid. But it may make it hard to iterate through a number of items.

Comment: I disagree.  This is not tabular data.  It's a tabular/grid layout, hence I would avoid tables.  That's what grid layouts are meant for.  Tabular data into tables? by all means but this is not such case

Comment: You can avoid table in this case. http://www.noupe.com/design/better-ui-design-proper-use-of-tables.html

Comment: If you like the layout of tables, but you're not actually displaying tabular data, you can use CSS3 `display:` `table`, `table-row` and/or `table-cell` property like this: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/getting_your_di