# How do I set equal widths for two divs side by side in a flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

With reference to [CSS side by side div's auto equal widths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351634/css-side-by-side-divs-auto-equal-widths), I am seeking to solve the same problem, only I am using flexbox and do not wish to use table styling for the content I'm displaying.

https://jsfiddle.net/rdh61g7c/

```css
#outer {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 768px;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div class="inner">Inner HTML content has larger natural width</div>
  
  <div class="inner">Inner HTML content has smaller natural width</div>
</div>
```

So the two columns' widths will stretch with their content but the left column will have a larger width as a result. To keep the two columns symmetrical about the center, I need the right column, which currently has a shorter width than the left column, to increase to equal the left. How do I do that in flexbox layout?

**Edit**: I see many of the answers basically assigning a fixed width to **both** containers (~50%). That's not what I'm looking for. The left container is free to stretch to whatever width the content needs, subject to a maximum, and that shouldn't be touched. The right container needs to expand its width to match the left.

Can this be done without resorting to JavaScript?

Comment: @Pete Here is one that does that, though one doesn't need flexbox for this: https://jsfiddle.net/rdh61g7c/8/

Comment: @LGSon ok I stand corrected but I think this would be more what the OP is wanting - they need it centred in that 1024 box: https://jsfiddle.net/rdh61g7c/10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve that one need to position the *right* as absolute and make the `outer` display inline.

As inline, the `outer` will size by its content, which is the *left*, which, as a flex item, also is sized by its content, and the *right* will not affect that, since it is positioned absolute and taken out of the normal flow.

Then, by simply push the *right* to the end of the *left*, it will render exactly how you want.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rdh61g7c/15/)

Stack snippet

```css
#outer {
  position: relative;  
  height: 300px;
  
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;  
}
.inner {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.inner:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

/* this is for styling purpose only, and produce a blue border */
#outer::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;  
  left: 0; top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div class="inner">
   Inner HTML content has larger natural width than the other
 </div>
  
  <div class="inner">
   This has a smaller natural width
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you in addition intended to always have the center of the 2 columns in the viewport middle, you can do like this (and if this is how you want, let me know and I'll explain what it does)

[Fiddle demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/rdh61g7c/16/)

Comment: Hi please see my update to the question. I'm not looking to fill the outer container fully. The left container width can be whatever it chooses but the right container must match it.

Comment: @thegreatjedi I updated my answer. This one does that https://jsfiddle.net/rdh61g7c/15/ ... and so does my second fiddle sample in my answer, though I also made that one to absolute center the right/left items.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the **flex** setting to the .inner elements:

```
.inner {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

This is a shorthand version of the flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis settings.

This will ensure that the remaining space of the #outer element is distributed equally to all child elements, no matter how many there are.

See following article for a full breakdown.

[CSS Tricks - A Complete Guide to Flexbox](http://CSS%20Tricks%20-%20A%20Complete%20Guide%20to%20Flexbox)

Comment: Hi please see my update to the question. I'm not looking to fill the outer container fully. The left container width can be whatever it chooses but the right container must match it.

Answer (score 1):

I woulld suggest to not use flex in this situation, but make the inner DIVs inline-blocks widht `width: 50%`. Note: In this case it's important that there is no linebreak between the DIVs in the HTML code - see my example below.

```css
#outer {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 768px;
}

.inner {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div class="inner">Inner HTML content has larger natural width</div><div 
  class="inner">Inner HTML content has smaller natural width</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you could use:

```
.inner {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

the easiest solution would be:

```
.inner {
  width: 50%;
  }
```

This gives the inner `<div>`'s a width of 50% of the `#outer div`. and 50 + 50 is 100%.

Comment: Hi please see my update to the question. I'm not looking to fill the outer container fully. The left container width can be whatever it chooses but the right container must match it.