# Get siblings of equal length with CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an issue where an element is auto-sized by an unknown image's dimensions. I'd like a sibling element to this image to be constrained by the same width as the image is set to. Without using javascript.

I've set up a pen to show what I mean:

```css
.container {
  display: table
}

.img-wrapper {
  line-height: 0
}

.info {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.info p {
  margin: 0 2vmin
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/500">
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/Slagon/pen/oNePqNo

Is it possible for `.info` to be as wide `.img-wrapper`? (Ignore that the dimensions are predefined in this pen).

Comment: So do you want the `p` to be the same width under the image or the same width to the right or left of the image?

Comment: @Kameron The same width to the right of the image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS side by side div's auto equal widths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351634/css-side-by-side-divs-auto-equal-widths)

Comment: @Fluxian Always make sure you are putting a `;` after each style you set in your CSS for it to work properly.

Comment: @HereticMonkey No that's for known width values.

Comment: @Kameron Pretty irrelevant as it doesn't address the question in any way and also false, you can always omit the last ;

Comment: Not sure why you would ever want to, just horrible practice. but hey keep doing you!  Should learn to be a little kinder to those trying to help you out

Comment: @Kameron Every CSS optimiser removes the last ; so I think it's indeed very good practice.

Comment: Umm... no, the only element with a width in the higher-voted answers have a percentage width on the parent element, corresponding to your `container` class. The other elements do not have fixed widths.

Comment: @HereticMonkey 
Well, don't know what the issue is then. But it behaves like this: https://codepen.io/Slagon/pen/wvqYwRY

Answer (score 0):

I used **Bootstrap** to solve this. Essentially how it works is a normal webpage spans `12 columns`. So in this case I put each of you divs in a `col-6` so that each element would take up half of the page. BOTH of these col-6 spans are contained by a `row`. Please see below.

```css
.container {
    display: block;
    justify-content: center;
}
.img-wrapper {
    line-height: 0;
}
.info {
    display: flex;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.col-6 > .img-wrapper > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

div.col-6 {
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
         <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/500">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
         <div class="info">
            <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

**Click full-page**

Comment: This solution doesn't let the image dictate anything. You're forcing the image to fit inside a column-6. This would be equal to just defining a fixed width and setting both elements to that, no matter how large the image is.